# AngularJS: Getting ngRoute working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ngroute

I'm working on a new Angularjs webapp where I have to use ngRoute. I'm a bit confused first, because routing doesn't work at all in my case – I always end up at `index` and MainCtrl.

in **index.html** I've included all dependencies like so:

```
<body ng-app="orderyourselfApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">{{hello}}</div>Soem random stuff

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/navbar.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
```

And I have the routes set up in `app.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('orderyourselfApp', [
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

And ofcourse, main.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('orderyourselfApp')

.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log('saysomething');
    $scope.hello = 'Hello world! LoginCtrl';
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log('shit is getting real');
    $http.get('/api/awesomeThings').success(function(awesomeThings) {
        $scope.awesomeThings = awesomeThings;
    });
});
```

Now, the issue is weird and simple: when I do a localhost:9000/login, I should get to the login.html template and LoginCtrl, but no. I keep ending up at `index` and `MainCtrl` and nothing seems to change the result.

**login.html**

```
  <body ng-app="orderyourselfApp">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">{{hello}}</div> … then the usual stuff
```

Where's this going wrong?

Comment: you have to use `ngView` directive somewhere in index.html, and login template will be inserted there. So it doesn't need ng-app anymore

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, `templateUrl` should point to your actual partial's relative path, for example: `templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'`.

Then, I think you should first land on `http://localhost:9000/` and then follow a link to `http://localhost:9000/login`

Anyway, you partials should not contain the `ng-app` declaration (they actually are partial). So you should have an `index.html` that would define your page's template, and two partials: `main.html` and `login.html`, ***neither*** of which should contain the `ng-app` declaration.

Ending in something like this:

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

With index.html being the page's landing from `http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: Also there has to be <div ng-view></div> in index.html

Comment: @blint you're partially right, what works is adding the ng-view to index, but adding the full path in the `templateUrl` is not needed.

Comment: Another +1 to @coni2k for ng-view. Saved my night!